# How to write newline in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail-api, template-literals

how can I write multiline string google script

```
"Dear "+mailData.name+","+"Thank you for writing to us. We have received your message about "+mailData.subject+
      " and will get back to you within 24 hours. Until then, you can give us an email sm@g.com\n\n"+
   "Thankyou \r "
```

Comment: You need to use '\n' whichever position you want to break into a new line.

Comment: For documentation purposes, please consider accepting an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an html body instead. You also need to modify your [MailApp.sendEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app) function to include **htmlBody** in the arguments.

Here is the solution:

```
var email_body = 
      `Dear ${mailData.name},  <br/>
      Thank you for writing to us. We have received your message about ${mailData.subject}. <br/>
     and will get back to you within 24 hours. Until then, you can give us an email sm@g.com. <br/>
     Thank you <br/><br/>`
  
  MailApp.sendEmail( {to:mailData.email, subject:mailData.subject, body:email_body,htmlBody:email_body}); // subject
```

Note that `<br/><br/>` will generate two new lines and `<br/>` will generate one.

Read more information regarding Template literals [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a line break to a plaintext email use "/n" as suggested by #Sounak-Saha in the comment above.

"Dear "+mailData.name+","+"\nThank you for writing to us. We have received your message about "+mailData.subject+" and will get back to you within 24 hours. Until then, you can give us an email sm@g.com"+ "\n" + "\nThankyou"

See Class paragraph here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph